# Craft update doesn't update

Tags: auto-updates

I am trying to update Craft, but when I do, it says update complete, but still shows that there is an update available. It stays on version 2.5.2759 but never updates to the latest 2.6.2776 version. I am running PHP 5.5 and Craft is installed locally.

Any ideas how I can diagnose what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The update process gets extensively logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`, so that's the place to go to start diagnosing.  You can search for `[error]` once you find where the update logs start and see if it reveals anything useful.

If nothing jumps out at you, you can contact support@craftcms.com and they can help diagnose the issue.